# Input value não imprime completamente variável com espaço

Tags: php, mysql

bom dia.
estou com um problema aqui, quando vou fazer update de uma página com dados vindos do banco os select option mostra os dados corretamente porém os value capturados não estão corretos, um exemplo, se for de cidades vem no value somente o primeiro nome da cidade enquanto na exibição do nome vem completo, logo, quando faço o update grava somente o primeiro nome, pois esta se dividindo e criando campos.
o que eu preciso é que na página do update o select option venha com os dados que estão no banco.

```
    <select class="form-control" name="cidade">
  <option value="">-- Selecionar --</option>
  <?php
$curc4 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM comarca ORDER BY comarc asc");
while ($lic4 = $curc4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<option value=".$lic4['comarc']." ".($cidade == $lic4['comarc'] ? "selected":"")." >".$lic4['comarc']."</option>";
} ?> 
</select>

//solução encontrada

<select class="form-control" name="cidag">
                        <option value="">-- Selecionar --</option>
                        <?php
                        $curc4 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM comarca ORDER BY comarc asc");
                        while ($lic4 = $curc4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                          $comarc=$lic4['comarc'];
                          if($cidag == $comarc){
                            $selected = "selected";
                          } else {
                            $selected = " ";
                          }
                           ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $comarc;?>" <?php echo $selected;?> ><?php echo $comarc;?></option>
                       <?php } ?> 
                      </select>
```

no console mostra desta forma

```
<option value="ANGRA" dos="" reis="">ANGRA DOS REIS</option>
```

desde já agradeço ajuda fornecida

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloca o values dos options entre aspas value=" .... "   que vai dar certo

Se preferir pode ser entre aspas simples  value=' .... '

```
echo "<option value=\"".$lic4['comarc']."\" ".($cidade == $lic4['comarc'] ? "selected":"").">".$lic4['comarc']."</option>";
```

> > O browser interpreta o valor da propriedade `value` COM ESPAÇO como sendo duas propriedades. **A solução é abraçar com aspas**.

### OBS

No firefox, observei que o atributo "`selected`" não funciona, a menos que você coloque o `select` dentro de um formulário, onde o formulário tem um atributo `name`.

Para evitar qualquer problema use `selected='selected'`

```
echo "<select class=\"form-control\" name=\"cidag\">
     <option value=\"\">-- Selecionar --</option>";
                    
        $curc4 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM comarca ORDER BY comarc asc");
        while ($lic4 = $curc4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                      
      /*######### com aspas simples ficaria assim ###########################################################################
       echo "<option value='".$lic4['comarc'']."' ".($cidag == $lic4['comarc''] ? "selected='selected'":"").">".$lic4['comarc'']."</option>";
      ###################################################################### */
                      
       echo "<option value=\"".$lic4['comarc'']."\" ".($cidag == $lic4['comarc''] ? "selected='selected'":"").">".$lic4['comarc'']."</option>";
       }
       echo "</select>";
```

Comment: quase perfeito Leo, unico problema é que os select option esta vindo vazio na página do update, deveria vir com os dados que estão no banco. no console o erro que estava antes desapareceu, foi resolvido.

Comment: na verdade no log esta vindo desta forma <option value="ANGRA DOS REIS Selected">ANGRA DOS REIS</option>

Comment: @Gerson, é só questão de colocação da aspas

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: hahaha, levei uma surra pra colocar as aspas no lugar certo

Comment: fiz outras alterações aqui, porém o select option continua vindo vazio, se eu trabalhar com id em vez do nome funciona como feito no primeiro código quando postei a dúvida, mas com nomes não estou conseguindo.

Comment: eu não me expressei direito, as opções do select vem normal com todos os dados para escolha, só que não aparece a cidade selected que esta setada no banco de dados quando abre a página para edição, este vem em vazio, daí eu teria que selecionar novamente.

Comment: vou verificar se há outro erro que esteja atrapalhando e retorno caso encontre.

Comment: @Gerson é só copiar o que está na minha resposta e substituir no seu código. Se não funcionar direito o erro está em outra parte do seu código que não está postado na pergunta.

Comment: desde já agradeço sua ajuda, porém só consegui fazer funcionar conforme edição acima . Muito obrigado.

Comment: Certo, mas repara que você fez exatamente o que te sugeri, abraçar o VALUE com aspas <option value="<?php echo $comarc;?>" só que de forma diferente, segmentou o PHP. Vou editar a resposta